# Python: To check for prime and increment

Tags: python

i have exactly 5 days of practise, an hour daily so kindly forgive if my questions are very low level. No prior coding exp

My objective of the below code is
1- check if entered number is a prime
2- if not print the next biggest prime

```
def primetest (num):       # check if number is a prime
    for c in range (2, num):
     if num % c == 0:
      repeattest (num)     #not prime? increment number
     else :
      print (num,"is a prime number")
      break       

def repeattest (num):     # check prime if not increment number by 1      
 for z in range (2, num):
   num = num+1
   primetest (num)
   if num % z == 0:
      num = num+1
   else:
      print ("Next Prime:", num+1)
      break

num = int (input ("enter a number:"))     # main code: 
for y in range (2, num):
  if num % y == 0:
        repeattest (num)
  else:
      print (num,"is a prime number")
      break
```

I think the logic is fine, but not sure why im not getting an output. Please help

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the output?

Comment: I am not sure but yes there are so many wrong things happening.

Comment: `for c in range (2, num):`: too long. Test until `sqrt(num)+1`

Answer (score 0):

The way you have done has a lot of errors not efficient. By making some modification to your code i have made it much simpler. Read the comments to understand:

```
def primetest (num):       # check if number is a prime
    return(all(num % i for i in range(2, num)))

num = int (input ("enter a number:"))     # main code:

while True: #loop continues until prime number found(True)
    if primetest(num):
        print(num,"is a prime number.")
        break #(stops loop if prime found)
    else: #otherwise repeat by incrementing to the next num until found
        print(num,"is not a prime number.")
        num += 1
```

Output:

```
enter a number:45
45 is not a prime number.
46 is not a prime number.
47 is a prime number.
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, i'm still a novice. I understand what you did here: return(all(num % i for i in range(2, num)))   <-- divide 45 by 2, 3, 4,5...44 but then what happens? return all..what value does it return?

Comment: it return a boolean value either True or False. True if prime ,False if not prime so this value is then used in the if statement. if primetest(num).