# Python - Prime check and increment

Tags: python

My objective of the below code is

1. check if entered number is a prime
2. if not print the next biggest prime

---

```
def primetest (num):     
    for c in range (2, num):      
     if num % c == 0:  
      repeattest (num)         #not prime? increment number
     else :  
      print (num,"is a prime number")  
      break         

def repeattest (num):     # check prime if not increment number by 1        
 for z in range (2, num):  
   num = num+1  
   primetest (num)    
   if num % z == 0:  
      num = num+1  
   else:  
      print ("Next Prime:", num+1)  
      break  

num = int (input ("enter a number:"))       # main code: 
for y in range (2, num):   
  if num % y == 0:  
        repeattest (num)  
  else:  
      print (num,"is a prime number")  
      break
```

I think the logic is fine, but not sure why im not getting any output.

Comment: The indention s=is really weird

Comment: 1. You should run `c` from `2` to `math.sqrt(num)`, for better efficiency. Also, take another look at your logic. Seems off.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: To check for prime and increment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41661490/python-to-check-for-prime-and-increment)

Answer (score 1):

Time comlexity of your code is O(N) when it find a number which is prime or not.
There is no pointing on dividing from 2 to len(num)-1. It is enough to loop from 2 to sqrt of the given number. Therefore time complexity reduce to O(n) to O(log(n)).

```
import math
num = int (input ("enter a number:"))

def primeTest(num):
    isPrime = 0
    for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(num)+1)):
        if num%i == 0:
            isPrime  = isPrime + 1
            break
    if isPrime == 0:
        print(num, "is a prime number")
    else:
        num = num + 1
        repeatTest(num)

def repeatTest (num):
    isPrime = 0
    for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(num))):
        if num%i == 0:
            isPrime  = isPrime + 1
            break
    if isPrime == 0:
        print("Next Prime: ", num)
    else:
        num = num + 1
        repeatTest(num)

primeTest(num)
```

Comment: This program prints prime for each input. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

The logic which you are using to find if a number if prime seems wrong .

Taking a integer like 9 prints "9 is a prime number" .

And also you are checking for next prime numbers from 2 to Num . 
Num being the input , you cant get a number greater than that . 
It exits from the loop without even getting in , therefore not printing anything when you are searching for next prime .

You need to change the logic .

write a separate function for checking prime and end the loop when you find the next prime number instead of stopping at num .